# How to fit and insert PDF onto a page with a subsection?

Tags: graphics, formatting, pdf

How to fit and insert PDF onto a page with a subsection? I tried using this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\section{important}
\subsection{less important}
\includepdf[scale=0.8,pages={1-1}]{samplepdf}
\end{document}
```

But that didn't work. I just want the PDF to be a little smaller, or cut, and included on the same page as the subsection. Is this possible?

Comment: You could use `\includegraphics`...

Answer (score 1):

You could use \includegraphics, but with \includepdf it works like this (the frame is from the example image):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}

\includepdf[scale=0.8,pages={1-1},
            pagecommand={\section{important}\subsection{less important}},
            offset=0cm -1cm]%a bit offset
 {example-image-letter}
\end{document}
```